# Combining a varying number of rows with matching IDs

Tags: sql

I need to combine multiple rows.

- Each row has an ID and a sub ID.
- IDs identify the user and the Sub ID identifies the contract period.

I need to combine rows based on these and grab other columns.

Example:

```
ID      SubID   StartDate   StartVal   EndDate   
123456   1      37622       100        37686   
123456   2      37781       20         37782   
254896   22     38584       44         38658   
254896   23     38722       18         38766   
254896   24     38825       6          38890   
254896   25     38972       68         39011     
365897   1      39696       38         41191
```

and I'm aiming for

```
ID     StartDate1 StartVal1 EndDate1 EndValue1 StartDate2   StartVal2 EndDate2 EndValue2....  
123456 37622      100       37686    26        37781        20          37782  65                  
254896 38584      44        38658    59        38722        18          38766  20....
365897 39696      38        41191    71
```

or

```
ID     StartDate               StartVal    EndDate                 EndValue
123456 37622,37688             81,8        37637,37722             12,90
254896 38584,38740,38796,38836 98,22,68,10 38670,38788,38796,38925 6,10,31,57
365897 39696                   7           41191                   74
```

How can I do that?

Comment: My advice is to google `SQL dynamic PIVOT multiple columns`

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I will have a look.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins for this:

`Select * from USER join ContactPeriod ON User."some common attribute of both tables" ="Contact.that attribute"`